# How to sort a hashmap whose keys are models?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

I have Hashmap for example

```
Map<EmailCategoryModel, List<EmailBlogDetailsModel>> map;
```

how do I sort Map based on some property of key?

Comment: You want sort.. what? the map? sort the `List<EmailBlogDetailsModel>`?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera, I want to sort map

Comment: The only map that you can sort is a LinkedHashMap, by definition a map hasn't order.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera A `LinkedHashMap` is not really sorted by a property, it just has the same order as the entries are putted in.

Comment: I would use a `java.util.TreeMap`. Since your model does not implement `Comparable` you need to set a `Comparator`.

Comment: @StefanWarminski You are right, but you can 'sort' it in this way: `Map<EmailCategoryModel, List<EmailBlogDetailsModel>> orderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(map.size());
       map.entrySet().stream().sorted( (a, b) -> a.getKey().getProperty().compareTo(b.getKey().getProperty())).forEach(e ->  orderedMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));`

Comment: (source: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902801/how-to-sort-hashmap-based-on-property-of-key-object-when-values-of-hashmap-are-s#comment42358548_26902801)) "It's generally best to avoid sorting a Mapping structure. The reason being is a map is supposed to be a lookup table. When finding a value, it takes O(1) time to look it up. There is no need to sort it. I would consider going with a different data structure if possible."

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeMap which is a sorted map and then use comparator or comparable interface.
Code:

```
// Use TreeMap like this

TreeMap<EmailCategoryModel, EmailBlogDetailsModel> map = new TreeMap<>(new ComparatorNew());

// And create comparator somewhat like this
class ComparatorNew implements Comparator<EmailCategoryModel> {

    @Override
    public int compare(EmailCategoryModel o1, EmailCategoryModel o2) {
        // Do sorting based on your model attribute here.
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why `ComparatorNew` should extend `TreeMap`?

Comment: By writing `class ComparatorNew<EmailCategoryModel,EmailBlogDetailsModel>` you are *declaring* two generic types named `EmailCategoryModel` and `EmailBlogDetailsModel`. So effectively your code can be rewritten as `class ComparatorNew<T,U> implements Comparator<T>` which doesn't look right since it doesn't handle already existing `EmailCategoryModel` type. You most likely wanted `class ComparatorNewimplements Comparator<EmailCategoryModel>`

Comment: Agreed, Thanks @Pshemo

Comment: It seems beside generic type declaration I also deleted `implements` keyword from last code example in my previous comment. Just add it before `Comparator`

Comment: I didnt delete that from example